# Consider the sequence $a_n$ where $a_0=0$ and $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_n+6}$. Show that $a_n$ is contracting.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence $a_n$ where $a_0=0$ and $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_n+6}$. Show that $a_n$ is contracting. Conclude that the sequence $a_n$ converges and compute its limit.

I have been able to prove its bounded $0 < a_n <3$ and increasing, and have found its limit, but am not able to show its contracting.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Prove that $|f'(x)|<1$ for $f(x)=\sqrt{x+6}$ when $x >0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$f(x) - f(y) = \sqrt{x+6} - \sqrt{y+6} = \frac{x-y}{\sqrt{x+6} + \sqrt{y+6}}$$ so that $$|f(x) - f(y)| = \frac{|x-y|}{\sqrt{x+6} + \sqrt{y+6}} \le \frac{|x-y|}{2\sqrt 6}$$ provided that $x,y \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

A real $(a_n)$ sequence is called contractive if there exists a constant $0 < C < 1$ such that $$|a_{n+2} − a_{n+1}| ≤ C |a_{n+1} − a_n |$$ for all $n \geq 1$.

In case of your problem, we can drop the absolute values and derive the following.

$$a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_{n+1}+6} -\sqrt{a_{n}+6} = \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{\sqrt{a_{n+1}+6} + \sqrt{a_{n}+6}} \leq \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{6}}.$$

Please justify the chain of the inequalities.